# How to use $store.commit in Nuxt with @vue/composition-api

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuex, vue-composition-api

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>Vuex Typescript Test</h1>
    <button @click="handleLogin">click</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent } from '@vue/composition-api'

export default defineComponent({
  setup() {
    return {
      handleLogin() {
       // something....
      },
    }
  },
})
</script>
```

`@vue/composition-api` do not apply `useStore`
I want to use store in setup function.

Comment: The way you're using `@click="handleLogin"` looks more like a `methods` here. Not really clear why you do want that in `setup`. Maybe you meant `function handleLogin() {`?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to access the `useStore` composable in the `setup` function according to the [documentation of Vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/composition-api.html#composition-api).

Your `script` section will look like this:

```js
import { defineComponent } from '@vue/composition-api';
import { useStore } from 'vuex';

export default defineComponent({
  setup() {
    return {
      const store = useStore();

      return {
        handleLogin {
          store.dispatch('auth/login');
        },
      };
    }
  },
});
```

---

The proper way to structure the content of `setup` would be to move the `handleLogin` as a separate `const` and expose the constant in the `return`, in order to keep the `return` section more readable like this:

```js
setup() {
  const store = useStore();
  const handleLogin = () => {
    store.dispatch('auth/login');
  };

  return {
    handleLogin,
  }
}
```